# Setting up GitHub Self-Hosted Runner On-Demand: Permission Denied Error

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to set up a GitHub self-hosted runner to run on-demand tasks using the reference from here [https://github.com/marketplace/actions/on-demand-self-hosted-aws-ec2-runner-for-github-actions.]

I've managed to set it up to a certain extent, but I'm encountering an issue when I run the **./run.sh** file. The error message I receive is:

`cp: cannot remove '/actions-runner/run-helper.sh' : Permission denied Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/actions-runner/_diag/Runner_20240217-utc.log' is denied` 
It seems to be a permission-related issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. I've double-checked my setup and everything seems to be configured correctly, but I'm still getting this error.

Any insights into what might be causing this permission denied error and how I can resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

It seems to be a permission-related issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. I've double-checked my setup and everything seems to be configured correctly, but I'm still getting this error.